# Other methods of automaic port forwarding besides uPnP

Tags: port, port-forwarding, upnp

Is there another method of auto-port forwarding, in case for some reason a user doesn't have uPnP enabled on the router? For programs like Skype, or IRC, how do they do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [hole punching](http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/) technique.